# How to find first empty line and delete with in the file using sed command regular expression

Tags: regex, file, find, line, is-empty

I need to find the first empty line in the text file using the `sed` command regular expression.

below is the content that I have

```
this is defile
to be cleaned
skip rest consl
```

In the above content, I need to find only the first line that is an empty line
and delete the first line.

I have used below regular expression, but it did not work for me, it is finding empty lines everywhere in the file.

```
^\s*$
```

Comment: How and where are you coding in what language? Can you share your codes/demo/efforts?

Comment: Do you need content of the first empty line, or its position, or what?

Comment: Try `(?m)\A\s*$`, it will  only match the first line if it is blank.

Comment: If you want to find the first blank line in a text editor and replace it use `^\s*$([\s\S]*)` and replace with `New line$1`

Comment: @ Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi -  I need the code with ```sed``` command in linux

Comment: See https://ideone.com/CzCiqP

Comment: @  Wiktor Stribiżew  - as per your answer I have the following sed command. ```sed -i '/(?m)\A\s*$/d' file.txt``` but it is not deleting the first line

Answer (score 0):

In Java you do something like this:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("^\\s*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher ("foo\n  \nbar");
if (matcher.find()) {
    String firstEmptyLine = matcher.group();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Mikhail  - I need ```sed``` command

Comment: And what do you need `sed` to do with first empty line?

Comment: I want to delete the first empty line